# show that this satisfy the triangular inequality

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, mahalanobis-distance

> Prove that the metrics $\rho(A,B)$ defined by :
> $$
> \rho(A,B) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{\mathbb P(A \bigtriangleup B)}{\mathbb P(A \bigcup B)}  & \text{if} 
>  \space \mathbb P(A \bigcup B) \neq 0 \\
> 0  & \text{if} \space \mathbb P(A \bigcup B) = 0 \\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> satisfy the triangular inequality.

What i was thinking was to use the fact that $ x \rightarrow \frac{a+x}{b+x}$ when a < b and $x \geq -a$ is increasing to swith from any C to subevent of $A \bigcup B$ and then normalizing the probability function, assume that $\mathbb P(A \bigcup B) = 1 $ but i don't know how to proceed.

I'm desperate in finding a solution.

Comment: As you are blocked on the general case, have you attempted to establish it for the simple discrete probability 
distribution, U([1,n]) (uniform on $n$ elements) : it amounts to counting a ratio of number of elements...

Comment: Honestly I have no idea what you're talking about. Instead, I was thinking about the application of the Jaccard distance on measures. What do you think?

Comment: I was tempted to give you this advice. I had written some time ago a question mentionning the definite positiveness of a certain matrix $A$ https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3173596/305862 in connection with Jaccard index. Maybe the property $\det(A)>0$ for the case $3 \times 3$ is equivalent to your looked for triangular property.

Comment: I saw it before, but i couldn't get anything useful for me, but surely for my bad.

Comment: "honestly, I have no idea what you are talking about". Maybe something is missing in your question leading to this misunderstanding of mine: you are working on subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (more exactly borelian subsets) and not on a general probability space...

Comment: This were the only conditions that the professor gave us, so no further info's